# Battery and wifi indicators on normal view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am using a simple view in application instead of navigation bar. Is their any way to show wifi, battery indicator on the view without using default navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean status bar? It is visible by default.If it is disabled, you can enable it from xib.

Also you can add the following code to make it visible :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return NO;
}
```